# how to make 2 divs hug center div?

Tags: html, css

3 divs: left/center/right. i want to position center div in the middle of browser (850px) and other 2 divs (225px each) hug it. how can i make this happen? i have a container and the 3 divs side inside of it. can someone help me

```
.container{

}


.left-content-area{
     width: 225px;
}

.main-content-area{
     width: 850px;
}

.right-content-area{
     width: 225px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the container the width of all the children, and center it. Then float the children beside each other. Use the `overflow` style on the container to make it contain the children (otherwise the container gets the height 0, and the children are shown outside it).

```
.container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.left-content-area{
  float: left;
   width: 225px;
}

.main-content-area{
  float: left;
   width: 850px;
}

.right-content-area{
  float: left;
   width: 225px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
.container{
   width:1300px;
   margin:auto;
}

.left-content-area{
     width: 225px;
   float:left;
}

.main-content-area{
     width: 850px;
    float:left;
}

.right-content-area{
     width: 225px;
    float:left;
}
```

The margin:auto gives the container an equal margin on the left and right, thus floating the it in the centre.

Float:left means the divs float next to each other rather than start on a new line.